# VLOOKUP to the left

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've read [this article](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/vlookup-left/) and tried it out myself with the formula

```
=VLOOKUP(C1;{Daten!B2:B10;Daten!A2:A10};2;false)
```

Note that I'm using the German version, so using ";" as delimiter is fine. This formula doesn't give me a syntax error but I get "#REF!" as error. Can somebody explain what I did wrong? By the way: If I write

```
=VLOOKUP(C1;{Daten!B2:B10;Daten!A2:A10};1;false)
```

instead it perfectly works fine and I just get the value of C1 back what is kind of pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your locale settings you have to use the backslash to create an array of columns:

```
{Daten!B2:B10\Daten!A2:A10}
```

A FYI, you could also change `FALSE` to `0`. Just a little shorter.